# Can anyone please show me how Coulomb first determined his constant $k_e$?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, history, coulombs-law

I looked at Coulomb's original experiment and can see how the relationship was derived to be an inverse square law but I assume he used maybe Hookes' Law? to get his constant. That was about 1784. The rest of my explanation of the question is based on assumptions as follows: Gauss's Theorem ( around 1813 ) which is equivalent? and the constant $k_e$ took on the form of the reciprocal of permittivity? What is the logical flow of how this constant was accepted in it's current form?

Comment: maybe more of a history of math and science stack exchange question...

Comment: By "its current form", do you mean $1/4\pi\varepsilon_0$? If not, why do you think that Coulomb had access to a reliable and reproducible standard of charge? Keep in mind that without a reproducible unit of charge, the constant Coulomb's law cannot be determined in a reliable way experiment to experiment.